# regex to capture the string between a word and first occurrence of a character

Tags: java, regex

Want to capture the string after the last slash and before the first occurrence of backward slash().

sample data:

1. sessionId=30a793b1-ed7e-464a-a630; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemSummary; sid=KJ4dgQGdhg7dDn1h0TLsqhsdfhsfhjhsdjfhjshdjfhjsfddscg139bjXZQdkbHpzf9l6wy1GdK5XZp; ,"myreferer":"https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemSummary/amex","Accept":"application/json,  application/javascript","sessionId":"ggh76734",
   targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=122;
2. sessionId=sfdsdfsd-ba57-4e21-a39f-34; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList?id=76734&para=jhjdfhj&type=new&ordertype=kjkf&memberid=273647632&iSearch=true; sid=Q4hWgR1GpQb8xWTLpQB2yyyzmYRgXgFlJLGTc0QJyZbW; ,"myreferer":"https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList/basket","Accept":"application/json,  application/javascript","sessionId":"ggh76734", targetUrl=https://www.example.com/ mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=123;
3. sessionId=0e1acab1-45b8-sdf3454fds-afc1-sdf435sdfds; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/; sid=hkm2gRSL2t5ScKSJKSJn3vg2sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfvJZkDD3ng0kYTjhNQw8mFZMn;  ,"myreferer":"https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList/","Accept":"application/json,  application/javascript","sessionId":"ggh76734",targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=343;List item
4. sessionId=sfdsdfsd-ba57-4e21-a39f-34; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList?id=76734&para=jhjdfhj&type=new&ordertype=kjkf&memberid=273647632&iSearch=true; sid=Q4hWgR1GpQb8xWTLpQB2yyyzmYRgXgFlJLGTc0QJyZbW; ,"myreferer":"https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList/basket?id=76734&para=jhjdfhj&type=new&ordertype=kjkf", "Accept":"application/json,  application/javascript","sessionId":"ggh76734", targetUrl=https://www.example.com/ mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=123;

Expecting the below output:

1. amex
2. basket
3. ''(empty string)
4. basket

Have build the below regex to capture it but its 100% accurate. It is capturing some additional part.

Regex

```
\bmyreferer\\\":\\\"\S+\/(.*?)\\\",
```

Could you please help me to improve the regex to get desired output?

Comment: Did the answer work out?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negated character class with a capture group:

```
\bmyreferer":"[^"]+/([^/"]*)"
```

- `\bmyreferer":"` Match literally preceded by a word boundary
- `[^"]+/` Match 1+ times any char except `"`, followed by a `/`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^/"]*` Optionally match (to also match an empty string) any char except `/` and `"`
- `)"` Close group 1 and match `"`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0sJEnM/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/8rIVDc)

Example code

```
String regex = "\\bmyreferer\":\"[^\"]+/([^/\"]*)\"";
String string = "sessionId=30a793b1-ed7e-464a-a630; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemSummary; sid=KJ4dgQGdhg7dDn1h0TLsqhsdfhsfhjhsdjfhjshdjfhjsfddscg139bjXZQdkbHpzf9l6wy1GdK5XZp; ,\"myreferer\":\"https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemSummary/amex\",\"Accept\":\"application/json, application/javascript\",\"sessionId\":\"ggh76734\", targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=122;\n\n"
+ "sessionId=sfdsdfsd-ba57-4e21-a39f-34; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList?id=76734&para=jhjdfhj&type=new&ordertype=kjkf&memberid=273647632&iSearch=true; sid=Q4hWgR1GpQb8xWTLpQB2yyyzmYRgXgFlJLGTc0QJyZbW; ,\"myreferer\":\"https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList/basket\",\"Accept\":\"application/json, application/javascript\",\"sessionId\":\"ggh76734\", targetUrl=https://www.example.com/ mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=123;\n\n"
+ "sessionId=0e1acab1-45b8-sdf3454fds-afc1-sdf435sdfds; Url=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/; sid=hkm2gRSL2t5ScKSJKSJn3vg2sfdsfdsfdsfdsfdfdsfdsfdsfvJZkDD3ng0kYTjhNQw8mFZMn; ,\"myreferer\":\"https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/itemList/\",\"Accept\":\"application/json, application/javascript\",\"sessionId\":\"ggh76734\",targetUrl=https://www.example.com/mybook/order/newbooking/page1?id=343;List item";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("Group 1 value: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
Group 1 value: amex
Group 1 value: basket
Group 1 value:
```

Comment: Thanks both of you! Its working fine.

Sometime the myreferer attribute containing query param (/basket?id=123). In that case its capturing whole string like "basket??id=76734&para=jhjdfhj&type=new&ordertype=kjkf". 
I have added the sample string and expected output in main post . Due to  comment length restriction I am unable to add here.

Could you please help me to enhance the Regex to get expected output.
Thanks in advance!